# c# WPF Combobox selected item text cut off

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

[image]

Not sure where in the combobox style I can fix this. If you need me to post code let me know, but the style code is pretty long. Below is the combobox less the style.

```
                    <ComboBox x:Name="user_combobox" Margin="115,62,0,0" Height="26" Width="306"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                              IsReadOnly="True"
                              Foreground="White" Background="SteelBlue" BorderBrush="White" OpacityMask="RoyalBlue"
                              Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxFlatStyle}"
                              ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ComboBoxItemFlatStyle}"
                              MaxDropDownHeight="{Binding User_Combobox_Height}"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Username_List}">

                        <ComboBox.Resources>
                            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxHighlightBrush" Color="RoyalBlue" />
                        </ComboBox.Resources>

                        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=username}" Margin="0,-1,0,1" Height="22" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>

                    </ComboBox>
```

Comment: did you tried with increasing ` Width="306"` ? by the way , this should be `Auto`

Comment: remove the `Height` ?

Comment: @EhsanUllahNazir Its not width I am worried about...its the height.

Comment: Then do the same with `Height`

Comment: @EhsanUllahNazir Already tested that...hence why I posted this question. If you look, the "g" is getting cut off at the bottom and yet there is space inside the control still.

Answer (score 2):

A wild guess, but is it possible that in your "ComboBoxFlatStyle" `Style`, you're setting a value for `Template` property of the `ComboBox`? If so, check your `Margin` value for any `Control` you've set there, you probably have some top or bottom margin that are too restrictive.

Comment: I will take a look at that. If you could throw an up vote that would be great. It is disheartening to see people down vote a legitimate question.

Comment: I sort of solved it I think by adjusting the `TextBlock` in the data template. I set `VerticalAlignment="Center"` and then bumped up the `Height` by 2. I was then able to remove adjusting `Margin` property so the text is where I like it and not cut off.

Answer (score 0):

I know, this answer is pretty old, but in case anyone faces the same issue again:

I had the same exact problem. I solved it thanks to the answer of Roger Leblanc. Changing widths and heights didn't change anything. But adding a Padding of 0 (or higher) solved it.