# C# WPF - Selected Item text is cut

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, datatemplate

The text in the SelectedItem of ComboBox is cutted.
In the example "Manual load" ---->> "Manual loa"
I tried to set Margin=0 and Padding=0 in  the template (as suggested in this topic "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48291742/c-sharp-wpf-combobox-selected-item-text-cut-off") but nothing works

My ComboBox

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbLoad" Padding="5,0,0,0" Grid.Column="1" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=Id_Name_Template}" SelectionChanged="Cmb_Load_SelectionChanged" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"/>
```

My Template

```
<DataTemplate  x:Key="Id_Name_Template" >
            <StackPanel >
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Margin="0" Padding="0" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <Run FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Id}"/>
                    </TextBlock >
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="-"  Margin="5,0,5,0"  Padding="0"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Margin="0" Padding="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontStyle="Italic" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
```

The result

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the `StackPanel` and set the `Width` of the `ColumnDefinitions`:

```
<DataTemplate  x:Key="Id_Name_Template" >
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Margin="0" Padding="0" VerticalAlignment="Center">
             <Run FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Id}"/>
        </TextBlock >
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="-"  Margin="5,0,5,0"  Padding="0"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Margin="0" Padding="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontStyle="Italic" Text="{Binding Name}" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: _"Get rid of the StackPanel"_ the solution to 90% of my WPF formatting problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `StackPanel` instead:

```
<DataTemplate  x:Key="Id_Name_Template" >
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizotnal">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <TextBlock Text=" - "/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontStyle="Italic"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Or just `Run`s in the `TextBox` itself:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="Id_Name_Template" >
     <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center">
          <Run Text="{Binding Id}" FontWeight="Bold"/><Run Text=" - "/><Run Text="{Binding Name}" FontStyle="Italic"/>
     </TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>
```